# Why is my webview on Android loading slowly?

Tags: android, pdf, android-webview

when I try the link in the browser, it opens very quickly
while on my Android `webview`, it runs slowly
what should i do so my `webview` can run faster?

```
webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                val title = response.body()?.attachment
                val filename = "http://lalala.com" + title
                webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + filename)
                webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH)
                webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE)
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                    webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
                }
                else {
                    webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
                }
                webview.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

                    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                        // do your stuff here
                        progressbar.visibility = View.GONE
                        webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                                "document.querySelector('[role=\"toolbar\"]').remove();})()")
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want use cache?

Comment: i want to load my webview faster @nupadhyaya

Comment: Then you should use cache. Remove this line `webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE)`

Comment: ok, i will try this

Comment: im sorry @nupadhyaya, it still load slowly

Comment: To load faster it depends on the connection speed.

Comment: @RashpalSingh why in browser this link open quickly, but in webview open slowly ?

Answer (score 1):

Unofortunately, there won't be much you can do to fix this. However:

There's a couple of things you can try though, and a few things to check. Specifically:

You're setting the visibility to View.GONE (making your webview invisible) while the page is loading, and then making it visible again when the page has loaded. This is probably the problem.

Try without this, and you will probably find that it will be quicker. In my experience, onPageFinished(..) only fires some time after the page is loaded.

Does the page really require JavaScript ? If not, don't enable it.

If it's feaseable in your case, you can use a HTML parser like Jsoup to extract only the desired data from the page, and show that to the user. This will be a lot faster.

If the page uses Ajax to load data dynamically, you can also load the data directly from the endpoints it uses. Open the page in a desktop browser, and open the network tab of developer tools to find out how the page works and loads data.

You can block requests from the WebView with shouldInterceptRequest(..). This may help if the page has things like eg. Facebook share buttons or extra images which you don't need. Blocking these will speed up load times.

If you show us the URL you're using, maybe I can investigate more and tell you axactly how you could speed it up in your case. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: i try this link in my browser can open quickly, but in webview so slowly https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/33580472.pdf